# Rubocop throwing issue on Date.strftime

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Iam trying to format a date with MONTH and YEAR format. But rubocop throws error as

> Prefer annotated tokens (like %s) over unannotated tokens in below line.

```
Date.parse(event.available_date).strftime('%B %Y')
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

As per the discussion here https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/5223 they have fixed the issue.

If the latest released version has the patch then you shouldn't be seeing the error after upgrading Rubocop.

Comment: I know it is fixed in latest version. Is there a way to do it without upgrading rubocop version.

Comment: You can disable that particular cop (Style/FormatStringToken).

Comment: ...Or you could fork the gem at whatever version you're using (?), and apply [the patch](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/commit/61e82fd1bb9b9d631f07242b71c7e3841e99e1c6). Just updating the gem version would clearly be the best solution however.